# How to extract a word from a link?

Tags: flutter, dart

Faced a problem. I get a link and I need to extract a `password-reset`, how can I do this? For example, to get `code` I use `queryParameters['code']`, but how do I extract the word `password-reset` from the link, I need this text for navigation?

**link**

```
https://test.test.test.test/app/password-reset?code=6294
```

**need to get**

```
password-reset
```

Comment: could you give more details or paste your code in the description so we can help you

Comment: I just need to extract from password-reset link

Comment: I have udated the question

Comment: Are you trying check if "password-reset" is in the link?

Comment: I need to extract this text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substring`, the code will extract the text between the last `/` and the first `?`:

```dart
var link = "https://test.test.test.test/app/password-reset?code=6294";

var start = link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
var end = link.indexOf('?');

var extract = link.substring(start,end);

print(extract);
```

Comment: Links of different lengths will fit here, right?

Comment: @Max Links with different text BEFORE the last `/` and the first `?` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same link, and know the index position of the letters.This would be helpful for you.

```
String myLink = 'https://test.test.test.test/app/password-reset?code=6294';
String wantedString = myLink.substring(32,46);
```

Comment: And if my link length changes constantly?